# Get the SQL Versions of all servers with get-wmiobject

Tags: sql, powershell, registry, wmi, get-wmiobject

I would like to get all the installed version values of SQL on over 200 different Servers.

The plan is, to have all the Server Names in the ServerListSQLVersions.txt
and to get all the SQL Versions into the CSV.

```
$Username = ''
$Password = ''
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$SecureString = $pass
# Users you password securly
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecureString

$Array = @()
##Create a Folder called SQLVersions##
$scriptPath = "C:\Transfer to SV000229\SQL Script"
$server = Get-Content "$scriptPath\ServerListSQLVersions.txt"
$wmiobj = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_product | where Name -like '*SQL*' | Select-Object name,version


function getWMIObject($server, $wmiobj, $MySecureCreds) {
     $result = Get-WmiObject $wmiobj -ComputerName $server -Credential $MySecureCreds 
     #Write-Host "Result: "$result
     $Array+= $Result
}  

$Array = Export-Csv $scriptpath\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

My output in the CSV is:

Length

0

Answer (score 0):

I used a

foreach($computer in $computers){

instead of the function and gave the information manually.

Also the output was not abled to Export, because i used an = instead of an |

Works now.